# MongoDB Find Query, dynamically change search keys based on key-value in a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-q

Country data looks like -

```
[{
   inEU : true,
   x    : {...},
   y    : {...}
}
{
   inEU : false,
   x    : {...},
   y    : {...}
}]
```

I need to choose either x or y object based on `inEU` field is set to true or false. X and Y object have the same keys (values/data is different).

**Find** query must use values from X if `inEU` is true else use Y object for search purpose.

Kindly let me know if its possible and if yes do provide any URL/links of documentation or any small example will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) to do that. For example:

```
Model.find( { $or: [ { inEU: true, x: condition }, { inEU: false, y: condition } ] } )...
```